# Good Bicycle Degreaser

Tags: road-bike, maintenance, cleaning

Today I cleaned my chain with the Park tool CM-52 and it was really effective. However, I ran through half of the park tool bicycle degreaser. I'm thinking of purchasing this degreaser from my local hardware store. Thoughts?

https://www.bunnings.com.au/diggers-1l-degreaser_p1560295

Comment: Best bet is for you to get the MSDS for each product, and compare their active ingredients.

Comment: Leave the fluid in the chain washer between uses.  (Set it carefully on a protected location on a shelf, or maybe even fix up a box with pads inside to hold it upright and catch any spills.)  Unless your chain is exceptionally dirty there is no need to change the fluid until after 4-5 uses.

Comment: Alternatively get a funnel and a dedicated chemicals bottle or an identical empty cleaner bottle (to avoid life threatening mix-ups) and fill the partly used cleaner in there.

Comment: I use WD40 as my solvent.  Utilizing a drip pan to catch the dirty solvent, I collect it in a plastic container. After a few days of lying still on the shelf, many of the solids settle out, and I decant the WD40 off into another container for use on another job.

Comment: There are some degreaser gels available now, such as the one made by Green Oil, which are much less messy than using a liquid degreaser.

Comment: Probably not a good idea, but gasoline used to be a common and inexpensive solvent.

Answer (score 4):

My fave chain cleaner is isopropyl alcohol. Cleans well and evaporates. Right now I use a jug of hand sanitizer that is alcohol plus aloe. Cheapish and readily available.

Comment: It is a good liquid to clean a brake rotor, but I doubt it will be too effective for chain. Even a simple soapy water should be better.

Comment: I use alcohol as a second pass after de greasing with paint thinner. To dry and evaporate chemical traces (grease and degreaser leftovers). Is alcohol enought to degrease wax lube? Wet lube?

Answer (score 3):

I use industrial citrus degreaser, diluted according to the directions printed on the jug. It works fine. (This is, according to the hardware storekeeper, most often used by restaurants to clean out their grease traps, so it's no lightweight product, and comes with mandatory safety and ingredient labels.)

Of course with any water-based degreaser it's super important to  to wash out lingering grit and degreaser residue. Rinse the chain carefully with water, then let the chain dry, then wipe it off, before putting on the lubricant you use.

You can use a lot of citrusy things as a cleaner. I've even used the orange Fanta soft drink in a pinch once. Just wash it off.

Answer (score 3):

İsopropyl alcohol is not strong enough to degrease a chain. For fast work, I use acetone.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the standing time between chain cleans to let the solids settle out, and decant the top part of the liquid off, which should be reusable.

If you can put a lid on the bottle/jar where you store the solvent, then leave it to sit quietly for a month.

This works best with a wide-mouthed glass jar with a lid that seals. You can see into it and the plastic won't be attacked by the solvent over time.

Simply carefully pour off the top part of the liquid into a second jar, and as soon as the stream gets a little murky then stop and dispose of the last part.  This may be as little as 5% of the mix, or as much as 1/3.

Optionally top-up your second jar with a little more fresh fluid and let the whole process run over the next ~month between cleanings.

Comment: That is amazing, I didn't know you could do that. Could I do this with any bike chain degreaser, do you think, like WD-40 for example?

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic give it a try- it'll only cost you a clean glass jar.   Basically you're allowing the larger solids to settle to the bottom and then decant the cleaner liquid off the top.